# cakephp translationos po files in plugins

Tags: cakephp

simple question but I cannot find the answer in the CakePHP 3 documentation. I have a global translation for each language, located in src/Locale/it_IT/default.po and I have also many plugins (for example) /plugins/myplugin/src/Locale/myplugin.po with translations as well. I thought that in case of duplicates (the same sentence in the plugin po and the default.po), CakePHP will take the plugin one, but I am not sure, if that is correct? Sometimes I updated the translation but CakePhp did not take the updates, I am not sure if it is the cache, but I always remove the cache after adding a new sentence to the po file like this " rm  -fr /tmp/cache/myplugin/".
Thanks

Comment: Solved! I just added a .ebextensions to remove the change the permissions of the cache folder, that's it!.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I just added a .ebextensions (for Elastic Beanstalk AWS) to remove and change the permissions of the cache folder, that's it!.